# Не запускается Qt Creator

Tags: windows, qt, windows-7, qtcreator

Долгое время у меня стоял Qt Creator и работал, но в один день (позавчера) перестал запускаться (появляется на 5-10 секунд в Диспетчер задач > Процессы и пропадает). Я подумал что переустановка поможет. Удалил uninstall-программой, которая была в Qt, а все что осталось уже руками почистил. Установил — результат тот же. Сейчас я уже где-то 5-й раз переустанавливаю. Реестр чистил. Повисит в процессах и всё.

**OS:** Windows 7 x64 .

**Qt Creator:** Qt 5.5.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.2, 852 MB) с которым в комплекте Qt Creator 3.5.1

**Внимание:** Скачивать заново пробовал. От администратора запускал. Совместимость ставил. Скачать отдельно Qt Creator тоже пробовал — та же история, не запускается.

Вот так висит 5-10 секунд.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой софт ставили перед возникновением проблемы?

Comment: Хм.. Ну Убинту как вторую ОС, всё.

Comment: Запустите проверку файловой системы из винды на всякий случай. Вдруг криво разделы создались...

Comment: Эмм.. Ну я точно не знаю что это такое, но сегодня при первом запуске она проверила всё файлы и не спрашивала меня. Так что я ставил уже после проверки.

Comment: Что ещё удивительно, так это то, что окно пытается появится. Мелькает и закрывается. + В интернете есть такие же вопросы, но людям помогала в таких случаях переустановка.

Answer (score 2):

Реестр чистить бесполезно - *QtCreator* почти ничего не хранит в реестре, его настройки находятся в каталоге

```
c:\Users\ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ\AppData\Roaming\QtProject\
```

Удалите этот каталог и запустите *QtCreator*. Должно помочь.